# How to handle null or empty value in multi layer project

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am working in Xamarin.android mobile application. I got some problem of crashing the app due to null value set to TextView.Text and ImageView from api call value. I wonder is there any better way to handle null value in any layer of application i.e. DataLayer or UI. As I have setup this structure in my project.
MyApplication.DA (for data access layer) and all my getters and setters are set under here. In this case, I have DA_WebSchoolNews.cs as

```
 public class NewsServiceRootObject
{
    public List<DA_NewsServiceResult> NewsServiceResult { get; set; }
}

public class DA_NewsServiceResult
{
    public string CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string PublishDate { get; set; }
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

In MyApplication.Core, which is shared project I have called webapi service to update data:

```
 public async void downloadJsonFeedAsync(string url)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        Task<string> contentTask = httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);

        // await! control returns to the caller and the task continues to run on another thread
        string content = await contentTask;
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Response Body: \r\n {0}", content);

        //Convert string to JSON object
        rootObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NewsServiceRootObject>(content);

    }
```

In MyApplication.UI, an UI layer in which I have created activities and fragments views. In my adapter class, I tried to handle null values so that view would not set any null values during run time, which I have done as follows

```
 DA_NewsServiceResult item = this[position];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Title)|| string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Description))
        {
            item.Title = "";
            item.Description = "";                             
        }

            var txtTitle = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Title).Text = Android.Text.Html.FromHtml(item.Title).ToString();
            var txtDescription = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Description).Text = Android.Text.Html.FromHtml(item.ShortDescription).ToString();
            var txtDate = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.news_date).Text = GetCustomDateTime(ConvertToDate(item.PublishDate));
```

what is the best way to handle null or empty for string, date time , int or float type data and how. I will appreciate with sample lines of code if applicable. Thank you.

Comment: "null or empty" for int is an interesting concept... The best part is `int` can't be null or empty ever - so you don't need to handle such cases.

Answer (score 2):

In your Data Transfer Object (`DA_NewsServiceResult` in your case) you could make all Value Type properties nullable (e.g. `int?` / `Nullable<int>`, `DateTime?`, etc.).

In your view layer you could then always handle everything as an object and check for null and then do what's best for the view (maybe hide the view element that would usually display the value)

That could be handled in a pretty generic and reusable method to which you pass the properties value and maybe a callback for what to do with a valid value (and an optional callback for what do execute when a null value is encountered)

(as a side note - it's always a good idea to use `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime` on DTOs (or basically anywhere) since it includes the offset from the UTC and could more easily be converted into local time / time zone specific time)

---

Alternative approach:

Make a generic extension method and check whether the given value is the default value. E.g. like so.

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static bool IsDefaultValue<TObject>(this TObject @object)
    {
        return EqualityComparer<TObject>.Default.Equals(@object, default(TObject));
    }
}
```

With that you could check every property for whether it is the default (has not been set for structs / value types and `null` for class objects) and act accordingly.

---

### Addition for string check

If you were to encounter a null string but wanted to use an empty string on your view you could to the following.

```
var txtTitle = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Title).Text = Android.Text.Html.FromHtml(item.Title ?? "").ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you woelliJ this is what I was looking for use of generic and how it works. I am gonna use in my project.

Comment: I have a quick question, in the case of object type DA_NewsServiceResult for example, shall I have to use loop to check all the items of list or just for object type only once. ` public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(T value)
        {
            if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
                return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value as string);

            return value == null || value.Equals(default(T));
        }`

Comment: For the special case of a string you'd have to check for "string.empty" or whitespaces separately, yeah. That does not fall under 'default(string)'. You could add another extension method that checks 'IsDefaultOrEmpty' that checks that separately. (

Comment: I've updated my answers to include something for your particular case. With the '??' operator you can easily check for null and use a default value if it is null. (Which is another benefit of using nullable value types)

Comment: Can I use this way?  DA_NewsServiceResult item = this[position];
            var isNullorEmpty=NullOrEmpty.IsNullOrEmpty<DA_NewsServiceResult>(item);
            if(isNullorEmpty)
            {
                //do something
            }
            else
            {
                // do something
            } I wonder how can I use in my setters?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146269/discussion-between-ishwor-khanal-and-woellij).

Comment: I have one question for you. May I set '?? ""' ' this default value while writing class and properties. For example, public class DA_NewsServiceResult{ public string Title{get return title ?? ""; set title=value;} instead of setting where needed (item.Title ?? "" )Thank You

Comment: Yes, you can do that too.

Answer (score 1):

First for **String**:

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(string);
```

And for **DateTime**:

```
your_date == DateTime.MinValue
```

And for int **int and float** will never be null because it is a primitive types.

Comment: Interesting way to make distinction between `int` and `DateTime`... What about `System.Int32` and `int` - should they be handled different too?

Comment: No, I don't think they should handled differently.